# How to show that the index $[G: H]$ is invertible?

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading the book Elements of representation theory of associative algebras, volume 1. I have a question on page 176, the proof of Corollary 5.2. In order to applied (5.1)(b), we have to show that the index $[G: H]$ is is invertible as an element of $A=K$. In the proof of Corollary 5.2, $[G: H]=|G|/|H|=|G|$. We know that $p$ does not divide $|G|$. But how could we show that $|G|$ is invertible as an element in $K$? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every integer not divisible by $p$ is invertible when viewed as element of $\mathbb F_p$ because not being divisible by $p$ in $\mathbb Z$ corresponds to not being $0$ in the field $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: thank you very much. But $K$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: $K$ is of characteristic $p$, therefore it always contain a subfield $\mathbb{F}_p$, generated by identity 1 additively.